# Parse the response string of a request into another method in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm trying to parse a response header value (which is a string) of one request into another method or function in gatling. Here is what I tried

```
val scn = scenario("DeviceAuth")
.feed(csvFeeeder)
.exec(http("Request1")
  .post("endpoint")
  .headers(headers_0)
  .formParam("key", "value")
  .check(headerRegex("header","pattern.*)").saveAs("value"))
  .check(status.is(401)))
object getHeader{
def authenticationHeader: String = {
val header: String = "${value}"
val s = header.split("")
     --so on and so forth--
}
}
```

So, when I tried to print the header value, it's just printed "${value}.
How can we pass that value into my function?

Comment: Please use \`${value}\` instead "${value}"

Comment: @Eugene used ` `${value}` ` in place of `"${value}"` Got an exception saying `${value}` not found

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution

```
val scn = scenario("DeviceAuth")
.feed(csvFeeeder)
.exec(http("Request1")
  .post("endpoint")
  .headers(headers_0)
  .formParam("key", "value")
  .check(headerRegex("header","pattern.*)").saveAs(value))
  .check(status.is(401)))
object getHeader{
def authenticationHeader: String = {
val header: String = `$value`
val s = header.split("")
     --so on and so forth--
}
}
```

Comment: I used val header: String = ` `$value` ` but, I got this error `illegal start of simple pattern`

Comment: Are you saved it as _saveAs(value)_?